# infuse a sum of the value in the another column with a different filter than the total count column

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate, case

First here's a sample table.

[image]

```
Provider_name patient       date        status  length
AF          AGUIR00001  07/05/2018  3       30
AF          ABBOT00001  07/05/2018          30
BB          ADAMS00001  07/05/2018  3       30
BB          ACEVE00001  07/06/2018  3       30
```

I have created a query that lets me count the total number of appointments versus the number of appointments with a certain status(eg checked out). I was able to create it and group it by provider.

```
select provider_name,
    count(patient) total,
    sum(case when status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as Checkedout
from appointment
group by provider_name
```

Then I moved on to the next phase which was to get the total length of those appointments with checkedout status. I made this query but it does not break down into each provider.

```
select provider_name,
    count(patient) total,
    sum(case when status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as Checkedout,
    (select sum(length) from appointment where status = 3 
and date between '06/01/2018' and '07/06/2018') 
from appointment where date between '06/01/2018' and '07/06/2018'
group by provider_name
```

I need it so that the last column in the query is segregated per provider_name.

Thank you in advance for helping me out.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you actual question is. Can you [edit] the question and make it clear what you are trying to do, what you have tried, and what results you get?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was not sure exactly how to phrase it so I made sure the body/description of my question is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you were on the right way, try this:

```
select provider_name,
       count(patient) total,
       sum(case when status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as Checkedout,
       sum(case when status = 3 then length else 0 end) as len_status3
  from appointment
 where date between '2018-01-06' and '2018-06-07'
 group by provider_name;
```

According to your last comment, you need a [**WITH ROLLUP** *modifier for* **GROUP BY**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-modifiers.html) as in the following :

```
select coalesce(provider_name,'Total') as provider_name,
       count(patient) total,
       sum(case when status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as Checkedout,
       sum(case when status = 3 then length else 0 end) as len_status3
  from appointment
 where date between '2018-01-06' and '2018-06-07'
 group by provider_name with rollup;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/906776/8)

Comment: If I have a followup question, can I post my question in the comments? I just wanted to know if we could add another row and get the sum of each 2nd, 3rd and 4th column.

eg
Provider_name     Total     Checked     Total Length
AF                           2             1                30
BB                           2              2                60
Total                        4              3               90

Comment: @geo007 I updated my question due to your comment but please edit your question by this detail also( extra sum row of subtotals )

Comment: SQL Fiddle Demo is sick!(in a good way) I'm running it in a SAP Advantage SQL Engine. I don't think it acknowledge the command "With Rollup". I'm getting this error message.
ERROR IN SCRIPT: poQuery: Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = 42000;   NativeError = 2117;  [SAP][Advantage SQL Engine]Unexpected token: with -- Expecting semicolon. -- Location of error in the SQL statement 
is: 317 (line: 7 column: 25)

Comment: @geo007 hmm I can't know about `sap`, and I suppose it was a `mysql` question(formerly tagged as so).

Comment: @geo007 no, there's  nothing bad to explore, do not underestimate your attempt.

Comment: maybe you need to convert back your date format with slash for your SAP Engine. I used `Default string literal format` (`yyyy-mm-dd`).

Comment: I actually tried both format with no joy. However, the error cursor is pointing on "WITH"

Comment: @geo007 as much as I know, you're using MySQL, aren't you? By the way which version ..?

Comment: SAP Sql. I mistakenly put mysql in the tags before. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

you shoul do as for checkedoutout

```
select provider_name,
    count(patient) total,
    sum(case when status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as Checkedout,
    sum( case when status = 3 then length else 0 )  as  total_length
from appointment where date between '06/01/2018' and '07/06/2018'
group by provider_name
```